# Solution of the PDE with Cauchy Data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of $$u_x+xu_y=y$$
Cauchy data:  $u(0,y)=y^2$.

If we write characteristic equation
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{y}$$
then, we find $c_1=x^2/2-y$. But I can' t find the other characteristic.

Please help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use your result and substitute $y=x^2/2-c_1$ into

$$dx/1 = du/y=du/(x^2/2-c_1) \implies u=\frac{1}{6}x^3-c_1x+c_2$$

Now, use $c_1=x^2/2-y$ and $c_2=F(c_1)$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I find $u(x,y)=x^3/3-y^2-yx$. ?

Comment: Sorry, It is wrong. $u(x,y)=-x^3/3+xy+x^4/4-x^2y+y^2$

Comment: What is wrong? My answer? It should be correct from the idea.

Comment: No my first answer was wrong :)